# Alternative for a loop

Tags: mysql, loops, alternate

I am trying to generate a simple report that will display the number of customers owning number of distinct brands. The following query I wrote generates the desired numbers one at a time. I tried writing a loop and it takes forever. Is there an alternative?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) 
FROM
(
SELECT customer_id,COUNT(DISTINCT brand) AS no_of_customers
FROM table_A
WHERE brand_id != 10
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT brand) =1 
ORDER BY customer_id) as t1;
```

What this does is to give me a count of customers with a total count of distinct brands =1. I change the count of brands to 2,3 and so on. Please let me know if there is a way to automate this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use a second level of `GROUP BY` to get them all in one query, rather than looping.

```
SELECT no_of_brands, COUNT(*) no_of_customers
FROM (SELECT customer_id, COUNT(DISTINCT brand) no_of_brands
      FROM Table_A
      WHERE brand_id != 10
      GROUP BY customer_id) x
GROUP BY no_of_brands
```

You also don't need `DISTINCT` in your outer query, since the inner query's grouping guarantees that the customer IDs will be distinct.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thanks it worked. Please ignore my earlier comment.

Comment: Fixed my answer. I had changed your original `no_of_customers` in the subquery to `no_of_brands`, but I forgot to change it in the `GROUP BY`.